# Calculate time spent on each Status

Tags: sql-server, reporting

Having the schedule log table as below:

```
ScheduleLogID   |ScheduleID |WorkerStatusID |StatusLogDatetime
------------------------------------------------------------------------
38              |202            |1          |2019-09-04 12:06:43.6216195
39              |202            |4          |2019-09-04 12:07:33.1519370
40              |202            |1          |2019-09-04 12:07:43.6976046
41              |202            |2          |2019-09-04 12:07:53.3540665
42              |202            |1          |2019-09-04 12:08:01.4505184
43              |202            |3          |2019-09-04 12:08:10.1397741
44              |202            |1          |2019-09-04 12:08:16.0210118
45              |202            |2          |2019-09-04 12:08:24.8038681
46              |202            |1          |2019-09-04 12:08:31.5119111
47              |202            |5          |2019-09-04 12:08:42.3227804
48              |224            |1          |2019-09-04 12:21:13.6859968
49              |224            |4          |2019-09-04 12:22:54.9930462
50              |224            |1          |2019-09-04 12:23:00.8586838
51              |224            |4          |2019-09-04 12:23:07.6291272
52              |224            |1          |2019-09-04 12:23:12.2779570
53              |224            |2          |2019-09-04 12:23:20.0936071
54              |224            |1          |2019-09-04 12:23:26.2556466
55              |224            |4          |2019-09-04 12:23:40.5921385
56              |224            |1          |2019-09-04 12:23:48.6417901
57              |224            |5          |2019-09-04 12:23:56.3482395
```

How can I calculate the total time spent in each `Status` for each `Schedule` ?

The result should look like this:

```
ScheduleID     |WorkerStatusID    |TimeSpent
--------------------------------------------
202            |1                 |06:30:00
202            |2                 |00:15:00
202            |3                 |00:30:00
202            |4                 |00:15:05
224            |1                 |06:45:00
224            |2                 |00:20:00
224            |3                 |00:25:00
224            |4                 |00:10:05
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to shove the problem? Also, please don't provide data as an image; the users you're asking for help from can't use it, making it somewhat useless. Provide data as tabular formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements.

Comment: What is the formula/logic behind calculating the total time ?

Comment: A `Worker` can be in different statuses: 1-Working, 2-Pause.... 5-Finished. I log the time and the Status every time he changes it and want to know how much time did he spent on each Status until he `Finished`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (my numbers do not match your sample results):

```
with mytablelead(ScheduleLogID, ScheduleID, WorkerStatusID, StatusLogDatetime, leadtime) as
(
select ScheduleLogID, ScheduleID, WorkerStatusID, StatusLogDatetime,
    lead(StatusLogDatetime) over(partition by ScheduleID order by StatusLogDatetime) as leadtime
from mytable
)
select ScheduleID, WorkerStatusID, sum(datediff(ss, StatusLogDatetime, leadtime)) as totalsecs
from mytablelead
group by ScheduleID, WorkerStatusID
order by ScheduleID, WorkerStatusID
```

Comment: its close and elegant :) The problem is that the last record of a `Schedule` takes the LeadTime of the first record of the next `Schedule` and it should be `NULL`

Comment: @FlamurDervishi I took ISNULL() out to give you NULL for the last record.

Comment: yes i know, but it produces `NULL` only for the last record of the last `Schedule`. Normally it should produce `NULL` for every last record of any `Schedule`

Comment: @FlamurDervishi Thank you for helping me understand the problem clearly. I made the appropriate change by adding a partition clause.

Comment: Thank you for the time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as the above approach but it is what i wanted:

```
SELECT OUTSL1.ScheduleID,
       OUTSL1.StartStatus as [Worker Status],
       SUM(DATEDIFF(s,OUTSL1.StartTime, OUTSL1.StopTime)) as TimeSpent
FROM (SELECT [SL].ScheduleID
            ,[SL].StatusLogDatetime as StartTime
            ,LEAD([SL].StatusLogDatetime) over(partition by [SL].ScheduleID order by [SL].StatusLogDatetime ASC) as StopTime
            ,[SL].WorkerStatusID as StartStatus
            ,LEAD([SL].WorkerStatusID) over(partition by [SL].ScheduleID order by [SL].StatusLogDatetime ASC) as StopStatus
      FROM [iFacility].[dbo].[tblScheduleLogs] as [SL]) as OUTSL1
WHERE OUTSL1.StartStatus = 1
GROUP BY ScheduleID, StartStatus
```

With the above query I manage to calculate it for `Status = 1`.
I did the same for the other `Statuses` and eventually a `UNION` of all these queries.